# How does s3 URL created for codedeploy and how to find with commit ID aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-code-deploy, aws-codecommit

I have been trying to figure out, how to find s3 URL or s3 object name which is created after the codedeploy deployment with new commit ID.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the aws-cli way to list application revisions and their s3 Location:

```
aws deploy list-application-revisions --application <your application name>
```

Example output:

```
{ "revisionType": "S3",
  "s3Location": {
       "bucket:" "mybucket",
       "key": "mys3objectname",
       "bundleType": "zip",
       "eTag": "ff1e77d70adaedfd14cecba209811a94"
   }
}
```

To construct an s3 url from this, use:
 `https://s3-<region>.amazonaws.com/<bucket>/<key>`

If you need to find your application name, use:

```
aws deploy list-applications
```

Comment: This will bring the current revisions, but I need to the find URL which is created for current commit

Comment: Like I have commited a file with comment "NEW CHANGES" and I have got a commit ID "cbe79a11-da91-412e-9579-b71ae9a11fad", now I want to know which s3 bucket is created for this.

Comment: Maybe you can describe your workflow more. Codedeploy can deploy from git or a registered revision from S3, since you mention S3 I took it you used s3 as storage for the deployment package.